# Can not use joined-subclass of xml mapping to extend the mappings build with NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am refacting the mapping of  [NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity) to `NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode` ,  as descripted in the issue https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/issues/16 .

I have rewrite the orignal xml mapping of `NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity` with `ClassMapping<T>`, the code looks like this:

```cs
public class IdentityRoleMappingPostgreSql : ClassMapping<IdentityRole> {

    public IdentityRoleMappingPostgreSql() {
        Schema("public");
        Table("aspnet_roles");
        Id(e => e.Id, id => {
            id.Column("id");
            id.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
            id.Length(32);
            id.Generator(Generators.TriggerIdentity);
        });
        Property(e => e.Name, prop => {
            prop.Column("name");
            prop.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
            prop.Length(64);
            prop.NotNullable(true);
            prop.Unique(true);
        });
        /* other property mappings ignored here .*/
    }

}
```

The full mapping code is here:

https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/tree/master/src/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/Entities

Then I try to extend these mappings with `joined-sublcass` of xml mapping, like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  namespace="WebTest.Entities" assembly="WebTest">

  <joined-subclass name="AppRole" schema="public" table="app_roles" extends="NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole, NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <key column="id" />
    <property name="Description" column="description" type="string" length="256" />
  </joined-subclass>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I got the following exception when setting up nhibernate:

```
NHibernate.MappingException : These classes referenced by 'extends' were not found:
FullName:NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole - Name:NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole, NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
FullName:NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser - Name:NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser, NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
   at NHibernate.Cfg.MappingsQueue.CheckNoUnavailableEntries()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildMappings()
   at UnitTest.IdentityTest._02_CanSetupMappingByXml()
```

Then I rewrite the xml mapping with `JoinedSubclassMapping<AppRole>` , which works , can build session factory and query without any exception.

```cs
public class AppRoleMapping : JoinedSubclassMapping<AppRole> {

    public AppRoleMapping() {
        ExplicitDeclarationsHolder
            .AddAsRootEntity(typeof(NHIdentityRole));
        Extends(typeof(NHIdentityRole));
        Schema("public");
        Table("app_roles");
        Key(k => k.Column("id"));
        Property(
            p => p.Description,
            maping => {
                maping.Column("description");
                maping.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
                maping.Length(256);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

So the issue is:

- when using `JoinedSubclassMapping<T>` to extend the mappings build with `ClassMapping<T>`, it works [_01_CanExtendByCodeWithByCode](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/blob/master/test/UnitTest/IdentityTest.cs#L17);
- when using `joined-subclass` of xml mapping to extend the mappings build with `ClassMapping<T>`,  get an exception of `NHibernate.MappingException : These classes referenced by 'extends' were not found`[_02_CanExtendByCodeWithXml](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/blob/master/test/UnitTest/IdentityTest.cs#L33);
- when using `joined-subclass` xml mapping  to extend `class` xml mapping, it works [_03_CanExtendXmlByXml](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/blob/master/test/UnitTest/IdentityTest.cs#L49);
- when using `JoinedSubclassMapping<AppRole>` to extend `class` mapping of xml, it works [_04_CanExtendXmlByByCode](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/blob/master/test/UnitTest/IdentityTest.cs#L65);

The full test code is here: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNetCore.Identity/blob/master/test/UnitTest/IdentityTest.cs

Maybe there something I do wrong, or some issues with nhibernate's mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug and check the source code of [NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Cfg/Configuration.cs#L1886), there is an internal validation queue to process the mappings added by xml, but now way to skip it, so the simple work around is converting the `HbmMapping` to xml, then add the xml to configuration, let's double check it.

```cs
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMapping<IdentityRoleMappingPostgreSql>();
// add other mapping here.
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
// Use AddXml instead of AddMappings
cfg.AddXml(mapping.AsString());
```